# Comparing two objects of the same class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

I am trying to overload the `==` operator in C++.

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace date_independent
{
    class clock
    {
        public:
            int clockPair[2] = {0,0};
            operator string() const
            {
                string hourString;
                string minString;
                if(clockPair[0]<10)
                {
                    hourString = "0"+to_string(clockPair[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    hourString = to_string(clockPair[0]);
                }
                if(clockPair[1]<10)
                {
                    minString  = "0"+to_string(clockPair[1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    minString = to_string(clockPair[1]);
                }
                return hourString+":"+minString;
            };
            bool operator ==(const clock&clockOne, const clock&clockTwo) const
            {
                return string(clockOne)==string(clockTwo);
            };
    };
};
```

There is much more code than I have included, but this is the important part. I want it so that the `==` operator can compare two objects of class `clock`. E.g., `object1==object2`. Is there anybody that can help me?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/1025391

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A binary operator like `==` can be overloaded either as a member function with a single parameter (`this` being the left-hand operand, and the parameter being the right-hand one), or as a non-member function with two parameters for the two operands.

So either

- move your operator declaration outside the class declaration (moving the definition to a source file, or declaring it `inline` if you keep the definition in the header); or
- add `friend` to the definition, so that it declares a non-member in the surrounding namespace; or
- remove the first argument from the member function, using `this` instead.

As a member, it would look like

```
bool operator==(const const & clockTwo) const {
    return string(*this) == string(clockTwo);
}
```

You might also want to compare the two integer values directly to save the expense of making strings. You should also remove the rogue `;` after the function and namespace definitions, although most modern compilers shouldn't object to their presence.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison function has been written to take two `clock` objects and compare them, so it should be a non-member function (after the class definition), without the `const` qualifier.

```
bool operator==(const clock& clockOne, const clock& clockTwo)
{
    return string(clockOne) == string(clockTwo);
}
```

When you have an operator inside the class definition, the left-hand argument is implicitly provided for you (it's `*this`), so if you wanted to implement it there you'd need something like:

```
bool operator==(const clock& clockTwo) const
{
    return string(*this) == string(clockTwo);
}
```

Still, that's not recommended for `==` as if you have say an implicit constructor from another type `T`, you won't be able to write code ala `my_t == my_clock` with the member version unless `T` provides a suitable comparison operator (for `clock` or `string`).  A non-member operator gives more symmetric operation.

Answer (score 1):

Though your question is poorly worded I believe that you are asking why the operator you've defined is not working?

If you are defining the operator as a member of the class it only takes one parameter. For example:

```
class clock {
    bool operator ==(const clock& rhsClock) const
    {
        // Note: this is the lhsClock
        return string(*this) == string(otherClock);
    }
};
```

When you define the operator as a **free function** (not as a part of the class) then you need to define both parameters:

```
class clock {
    // ... class declaration ...
};

bool operator ==(const clock& lhsClock, const clock& rhsClock)
{
    return string(lhsClock) == string(rhsClock)
}
```

Where the comparison would look like this:

```
if (lhsClock == rhsClock) // ... do something ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Overloading can be done inside or outside the class definition. If you want to do it inside, the function receives only one argument. You should compare `this` with that argument.

```
bool operator ==(const clock&clockTwo) const
{
    return string(*this)==string(clockTwo);
}
```

Note the `const` after the argument, it means that you won't change `this` inside the function.
On the other hand, if you want to do it outside the class definition, it needs two arguments, and you should compare them.

```
bool operator ==(const clock&clockOne, const clock&clockTwo)
{
    return string(clockOne)==string(clockTwo);
}
```

Also note that it'll be faster to compare the clockPair of the objects rather than making the string and comparing them.